# Python platformer game issue in going to the next level

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.5

I have made a platformer using Python 3.5 and have made the second level.

I want to go to the second level when you touch the blue area (represented by `E`). For now, the blue area exits the code, just to make sure the trigger is being triggered.

I have created the second level an put into an array.

---

This is my code:

```
def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 700)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level1 = [ #level as an array
        ]
    
    level2 = [ #level as an array
        ]
    
    # build the level
    for row in level1:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            if col == "L":
                l = Lava(x, y)
                platforms.append(l)
                entities.add(l)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    total_level_width  = len(level1[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level2)*32
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                raise SystemExit("ESCAPE")
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        camera.update(player)

        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        pygame.display.update()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#ff0000"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel -= 8
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if isinstance(p, Lava):
                    main()
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#7cfc00"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))
        
class Lava(Platform):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
            self.image.fill(Color("#ff0000"))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

I have attempted copying the `for row in level1:` and changing the exit function to change the variable, but it doesn't work.

---

Can anyone help?

Comment: "I have googled solutions, but none of them work on my code." This statement is useless unless you plan on sharing those solutions and explaining *exactly* why they failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it working. Heres the code, it works by basically re initializing platforms and entities to the desired value(corresponding with the level, too add more levels, have your level variable, and just say if

```
levelNum == 3:
     buildLevel(level3)
```

otherwise a more efficient method would put the in a list,and set level num too 0
Heres the full code, also , it might not work if you get "pass" level two because there is no level three, so you might want to just make it say congratulations or something.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
levelNum = 1
WIN_WIDTH = 1000
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30
def buildLevel(level):
    plats = []
    ents = pygame.sprite.Group()
    x,y = 0,0
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                plats.append(p)
                ents.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                plats.append(e)
                ents.add(e)
            if col == "L":
                l = Lava(x, y)
                plats.append(l)
                ents.add(l)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0
    return plats,ents
def main():
    global level2,player
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#87ceeb"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 700)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level1 = [
        "P PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P PE                                       P",
        "P PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP  P   P",
        "P                                   P   P",
        "P                                  P     P", 
        "P                                 P       P",
        "P                                P     P",
        "P            L     L        P       P",
        "P     PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP       P",
        "P  LLL                                   P",
        "P  LLL                                   P",
        "P  PPPP                                     P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                P                     P",
        "P     PPPP    PPPPPP                  P",
        "P                    PP                   P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                        PPPPPPPPPP       P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                 PPPP                 P",
        "P            PP                           P",
        "P   E      PP                         P",
        "P   PPPPLLLLLPP                           P",
        "P   PPPPPPLLLLLPPLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

    level2 = [
        "P PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P PE                                       P",
        "P PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP  P   P",
        "P                                   P   P",
        "P                                  P     P", 
        "P                                 P       P",
        "P                                P     P",
        "P            L     L        P       P",
        "P     PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP       P",
        "P  LLL                                   P",
        "P  LLL                                   P",
        "P  PPPP                                     P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                P                     P",
        "P     PPPP    PPPPPP                  P",
        "P                    PP                   P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                        PPPPPPPPPP       P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                 PPPP                 P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                                         P",
        "P                                         P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

    # build the level
    if levelNum ==1:
        platforms,entities = buildLevel(level1) 
    elif levelNum == 2:
        platforms,entities = buildLevel(level2) 
    total_level_width  = len(level1[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level2)*32
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                raise SystemExit("ESCAPE")
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        camera.update(player)

        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        pygame.display.update()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                          # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                          # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#ff0000"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel -= 8
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, plats):
        global levelNum
        for p in plats:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    levelNum+=1
                    main()  
                    #pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if isinstance(p, Lava):
                    main()
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#7cfc00"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))

class Lava(Platform):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
            self.image.fill(Color("#ff0000"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, can I add this function again to make more levels (like 10 more?)

Comment: Yeah, as I said, just either say         if  levelNum == 3: buildLevel(level3) or make them all in a list.